# splitting a command-line in to executable and arguments

Tags: c++, string

What is the best way in C++03 to split a command line in to two strings: executable and arguments?

For example:

- `"\"c:\\Program Files\\MyFile.exe\" /a /b /c" => "c:\Program Files\MyFile.exe", "/a /b /c"`
- `"c:\\Foo\\bar.exe -t \"myfile.txt\"" => "c:\Foo\bar.exe", "-t \"myfile.txt\""`
- `"baz.exe \"quantum conundrum\"" => "baz.exe", "\"quantum conundrum\""`

A good solution should handle both quotes and spaces.

boost is acceptable.

My current (working) solution:

```
void split_cmd( const std::string& cmd, 
                std::string* executable, 
                std::string* parameters )
{
    std::string c( cmd );
    size_t exec_end;
    boost::trim_all( c );
    if( c[ 0 ] == '\"' )
    {
        exec_end = c.find_first_of( '\"', 1 );
        if( std::string::npos != exec_end )
        {
            *executable = c.substr( 1, exec_end - 1 );
            *parameters = c.substr( exec_end + 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            *executable = c.substr( 1, exec_end );
            std::string().swap( *parameters );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exec_end = c.find_first_of( ' ', 0 );
        if( std::string::npos != exec_end )
        {
            *executable = c.substr( 0, exec_end );
            *parameters = c.substr( exec_end + 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            *executable = c.substr( 0, exec_end );
            std::string().swap( *parameters );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since ways that exist are demonstrably better than ways that don't exist, I'd say that your example **is** the "best way." You might rephrase your question "what's wrong with my way?" or "how can I improve my way?", in which case you should move your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are you passing parameters executable and parameters as pointers and not references?

Comment: Is this MS Windows problem? On *nix systems you just have (int argc, char* argv[]) - argv[0] is executable, argv[1]...argv[argc-1] - arguments...

Comment: @piokuc: I prefer output parameters to be non-const pointers. Because you have to prefix them with a &, it makes it more obvious that the variable will be modified. see-also: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Sort of. I have a string like this `"/Foo/Bar.exe /a /b /t"` I want to pass it to `CreateProcess` which takes two strings: the executable file and the arguments.

Comment: There are MS Windows functions designed for this task. I dont recall the name.

Comment: The CommandLineToArgvW could do similar job, but not good enough, it removes the quotes.